# Closure of an open set in manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I have a question. During a proof of a proposition, the following is stated:
Let $K$ be a compact set in a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$. Then there exists an open set $U$ such that $K\subset U$ and such that $\bar U$ is compact.

Why can we find this open set? Is it true that every closed is compact in a manifold? (I'd say that this is somehow implied by being locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{H}^n$ if it is true).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find such a $U$, note that, because $M$ is a manifold, each $x \in K$ has an open neighbourhood, $N_x$ say, that is homeomorphic to the open $n$-dimensional unit ball via a homeomorphism that extends to the closed $n$-dimensional unit ball. The union of the $N_x$ cover $K$, hence as $K$ is compact, a finite subset $N_{x_1}, N_{x_2}, \ldots N_{x_k}$ of the $N_x$ also covers $K$. Take $U$ to be the union of this finite subset. Then, $U$ is open, $K \subseteq U$ and the closure $\bar U$ is compact, because it is the (finite) union of the closures of the $N_{x_i}$ each of which is compact (because it is homeomorphic to the closed $n$-dimensional unit ball).

It is not true that every closed subset of a manifold is compact. E.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed but not compact subset of itself.

Comment: Maybe you can also mention that your edit was crucial. ;P As an illustration could serve: $M:=B, K:=\frac12\overline{B}:\quad N_x\equiv B$

Comment: @Freeze_S: I thought I had said so in the revision history, but, yes, my first version only worked for compact $M$.

Comment: why can we suppose the $N_x$ to be homeomorphic to a n-unit ball? I mean, can't there be, for example, a non neighbourhood? at this point he would not be homeomorphic to a unit ball

Comment: This follows from the definition of a manifold. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold

Answer (score 1):

Take a compact [neighbourhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_%28mathematics%29#Definition) $C_y$ of  each point  $y\in K$ and then extract a finite covering from the open covering $(\mathring C_y)_y$ .
Finally take  the union  of the finitely many selected $C_y$ 's.

[This construction works for any locally compact topological space :  the manifold structure is irrelevant]

Comment: Suggestion: Take just immediately the cover by compact neighborhoods. ;) *(The necessity of open cover is just an artefact of topology by opens.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S $\;$  I don't understand your comment: the union of all the $C_y$'s has no reason to be compact.

Comment: But they cover the compact so admit a finite subcover. *(In fact, all you need them to be is neighborhoods for every point at least one but not necessarily open.)*

Comment: Besides, from me: (+1)

Comment: Nice point, but the manifold structure is highly relevant if you don't know what "locally compact" means or that manifolds are locally compact :-). (I do, but I don't know if the OP does.)

Comment: @Freeze_S The definition of compact means that one can extract a finite covering from an **open** covering. Since the $C_y$'s are compact, they are not open . The misunderstanding is probably due to the fact that  I use "neighbourhood" in the sense of Bourbaki and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_%28mathematics%29#Definition), which doesn't require a neighbourhood to be open . I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: No wait wait, I know that you mean neighborhood in the sense of Bourbaki and that's why this becomes so beautiful. So my suggestion was also to not bother with necessarily open covers but covers by neighborhoods of every point that is precisely your construction.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: But I guess the way it is now is the most straightforward one. Great answer. :)

Comment: Dear Rob, I meant irrelevant in the logical sense that the property only depends on the poorer underlying topological structure of the manifold.  It may indeed very well be the case that manifolds are taught before local compactness at the OP's university. Most importantly, this was not meant as a criticism of your fine answer which I had **not** read while composing mine.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Your proof is so great, it is even superior to Rudin's, IMO. *(See Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, Theorem 2.7!)*